# Strange behaviour with Jersey multipart request for UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, utf-8, jersey-2.0

I have seen strange behavior with jersey and tomcat multipart request.
I have files in different languages example

минуты назад.txt or 您好.txt

With help of other post I figured out that we need to convert this in UTF-8 format.
Something like

```
String fileName=new String(bodyPart.getContentDisposition().getFileName().getBytes(),"UTF-8");
```

With this I see that the names are converted back but some characters are garbled with question marks. The above mentioned file names are converted to something like

> мин�?�?�? назад.txt and �?�好.txt

I am not sure why only few characters are lost. In above code bodyPart is nothing but FormDataBodyPart bodyPart from Jersey.
Is there any additional configuration needed in Tomcat ? I tried adding URIEncoding="UTF-8" but that did not help.

Need some help to understand this.